# Can't handle duplicates in a recursive "combination sum" method

Tags: c++, recursion, combinations

Problem: given a vector, find all the unique triplets such that a+b+c=0 (and return them in a vector of vectors)

The following code **almost** works: it finds all the possible triplets, including those with duplicates and those that are redundant (i.e.: [0,1,-1] and [-1,0,1])  so for the following case:

[-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]

it returns [-1,0,1],[-1,-1,2] but also, erroneously, [0,0,0],[2,2,-4] etc.

CODE:

```
vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
    vector<vector<int>> res;
    vector<int> temp;
    temp={};
    res={};
    if(nums.size()<3)
        return res;
    fillVector(nums,res,temp);
    return res;
}

void fillVector(vector<int> nums, vector<vector<int>>& ans, vector<int>& temp, int sum=0, int beg=0){
    //if I find a triplet a+b+c=0, add it to the result
    if(sum==0 && temp.size()==3){
        ans.push_back(temp);
        return;
    }
    //if the triplet returns a value !=0, don't add to the result
    if(temp.size()==3)
        return;
    for(int i=beg;i<nums.size();++i){
        int newSum=sum+nums[i];
        temp.push_back(nums[i]);
        fillVector(nums,ans,temp,newSum,i);
        temp.pop_back();
    }
}
```

In order to avoid the duplicates, I tried adding the line

```
nums.erase(nums.begin()+beg);
```

before the recursive call, but it doesn't work

Comment: I highly recommend taking the extra bit of effort to turn this into a runnable program so that potential answerers can run and experiment with it. It's usually worth the time spent.

Comment: What was your reasoning for believing that additional added line would solve your problem? Just curious.

Comment: I'd start by sorting the vector.

Comment: @WhozCraig I thought I would've been able to avoid re-including the same value more than one, basically reducing the size of the vector every time